# Bash script help/evaluation

Tags: bash

I'm trying to learn some scripting however I can't find solution for one functionality.

Basically I would like to ask to evaluate my script as it's probably possible to reduce the complexity and number of lines.

The purpose of this script is to download random, encrypted MySQL backups from Amazon S3, restore the dump and run some random MySQL queries.

I'm not sure how to email the output from `printf` statements - one is for headers and second one for actual data. I've tried to format the output so it looks like below but I had to exclude the headers from the `loop`:

```
Database:   Table:          Entries:                      

database1   random_table        0                             
database2   random_table        0                             
database3   random_table        0
database4   random_table        0
```

I would like to include this output in the email and also change the email subject based on the success/failure of the script.

I probably use to much `if` loops and MySQL queries are probably to complicated.

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# DB Details:
db_user="user"
db_pass="password"
db_host="localhost"

# Date
date_stamp=$(date +%d%m%Y)

# Initial Setup
data_dir="/tmp/backup"

# Checks
if [ ! -e /usr/bin/s3cmd ]; then
    echo "Required package (http://s3tools.org/s3cmd)"
    exit 2
fi
if [ -e /usr/bin/gpg ]; then

gpg_key=$(gpg -K | tr -d "{<,>}" | awk '/an@example.com/ { print $4 }')

if [ "$gpg_key" != "an@example.com" ]; then
    echo "No GPG key"
    exit 2
fi

else
    echo "No GPG package"
    exit 2
fi

if [ -d $data_dir ]; then
    rm -rf $data_dir/* && chmod 700 $data_dir
else
    mkdir $data_dir && chmod 700 $data_dir
fi

# S3 buckets
bucket_1=s3://test/

# Download backup

for backup in $(s3cmd ls s3://test/ | awk '{ print $2 }')
do
latest=$(s3cmd ls $backup | awk '{ print $2 }'  | sed -n '$p')
random=$(s3cmd ls $latest | shuf | awk '{ print $4 }' | sed -n '1p')
        s3cmd get $random $data_dir >/dev/null 2>&1
done

# Decrypting Files
for file in $(ls -A $data_dir)
do
filename=$(echo $file | sed 's/\.e//')
    gpg --out $data_dir/$filename --decrypt $data_dir/$file >/dev/null 2>&1 && rm -f $data_dir/$file
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

# Decompressing Files
bzip2 -d $data_dir/$filename
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Decompression Failed!"
fi
else
    echo "Decryption Failed!"
exit 2
fi
done

# MySQL Restore

printf "%-40s%-30s%-30s\n\n" Database: Table: Entries:

for dump in $(ls -A $data_dir)
do
    mysql -h $db_host -u $db_user -p$db_pass < $data_dir/$dump
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

# Random DBs query
db=$(echo $dump | sed 's/\.sql//')
random_table=$(mysql -h $db_host -u $db_user -p$db_pass $db -e "SHOW TABLES" | grep -v 'Tables' | shuf | sed -n '1p')
db_entries=$(mysql -h $db_host -u $db_user -p$db_pass $db -e "SELECT * FROM $random_table" | grep -v 'id' | wc -l)

printf "%-40s%-30s%-30s\n" $db $random_table $db_entries

    mysql -h $db_host -u $db_user -p$db_pass -e "DROP DATABASE $db"     
else
    echo "The system was unable to restore backups!"
    rm -rf $data_dir
exit 2
fi
done

#Remove backups
    rm -rf $data_dir
```

Comment: If you want someone generally to review your code, post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get the best answers if you ask specific questions (rather than, "please review my code")...and if you limit each post to a single question.  Regarding emailing the output of your printf statements:

You can group statements into a block and then pipe the output of a block into another program.  For example:

```
{
  echo "This is a header"
  echo

  for x in {1..10}; do
    echo "This is row $x"
  done
} | mail -s "Here is my output" lars@example.com
```

If you want to make the email subject conditional upon the success or
failure of something elsewhere in the script, you can (a) save your
output to a file, and then (b) email the file after building the
subject line:

```
{
  echo "This is a header"
  echo

  for x in {1..10}; do
    echo "This is row $x"
  done
} > output

if is_success; then
  subject="SUCCESS: Here is your output"
else
  subject="FAILURE: Here are your errors"
fi

mail -s "$subject" lars@example.com < output
```